# React is not rendering any elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I making a Markdown Previewer with React.

http://codepen.io/shreyas23-sk/pen/ObeGEm

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MarkdownRenderer/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

What is wrong here?

EDIT 1 : Ok, sorry to bug everyone, but it has stopped again.please check the same link once again. The elements were rendering, but they were printing blatant text and the elements as the output.So, I decided to do some research and use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Which created problems unknown, and now they are not rendering anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not linking to marked.js from its CDN. The link should be [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js) instead.

Also, what makes it actually not render is line 1 at `let marked = require('marked');` because marked isn't a node_module in this environment, including the script will give you the global marked available just as you can use React and React.DOM without 'requiring' them.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('root')
```

Note that you spelled getElementedById wrong! This should fix things.

Comment: if you go to the actual codepen you'll notice that there is no spelling mistake and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your question to show that you don't have a typo.

Codepen does not support requires like that, and your src link to the `marked` library is wrong - it should be [this](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js). Remove the require and fix the library and it renders just fine.

In the future open up your chrome console and look at this in detail, the answers were there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem Shreyas!

Problem lies in the way you imported your `marked` library.

---

## *1*

Replace an old link with a new one: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js

---

## *2*

Remove top line of your code ->
`let marked = require('marked');`